# Pick inferred type from unwrapped Promise type in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have a function `getStaticProps` (nextjs) that returns a Promise, resolving to an Object with
the following signature:

```
type StaticProps<P> = {
    props: P;
    revalidate?: number | boolean;
}
```

I can "unwrap" the type of the returned object generically via:

```
type UnwrappedPromiseType <T extends (...args: any) => any> =
    T extends (...args: any) => Promise<infer U> ? U :
        T extends (...args: any) => infer U ? U : any
```

From this resolved type **I only need the inferred type of `{props: {}}`**!
How can I `Pick` the type for {props: {}} from the returned Type?

complete example:

```
import { PrismaClient, Post } from "@prisma/client";
import Link from "next/link";
const prisma = new PrismaClient();

// ts correctly infers this to:
// () => Promise<{props: {posts: Array<Post>}}>
export const getStaticProps = async () => ({
  props: {
    posts: await prisma.post.findMany(),
  },
});

// i want to automatically infer the type for my props object 
const Posts = ({ posts = [] }: {posts: Post[]}) => (
  <main>
    <h1>Posts:</h1>
    <ul>
      {posts.map((post) => (
        <li key={post.id}>
          <Link href={`/posts/${post.id}`}>
            <a>{post.title}</a>
          </Link>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  </main>
);

export default Posts;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a `Pick` but [index types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types)

```
type PostProps = UnwrappedPromiseType<typeof getStaticProps>["props"];

const Posts = ({ posts = [] }: PostProps) => ( ... );
```